# Tying rails account to scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I have a rails application built on top of the [Devise cancan bootstrap](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan) repo.

I am trying to make a page for employee's to log hours. I set up a scaffold, and it generates a view with the form on that scaffold, but my question is how do I link to that page from the menu, and how can I make it so those logged hours are tied to whichever employee is logged in.

My scaffold is

```
rails g scaffold hours email:string day:date hours:integer
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be like a "shifting" functionnality, where employees say "I start working" and at the end of the day they say "I stop working now" and count the time, for each employee, eventually each day?

Comment: No, just I can log in, choose which day im submitting hours for, and say how many hours I worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So besides user creation and authentication Devise has added the following

- User model (backed by a users table in the database)
- current_user method available in your controller code and in your views

You want to use a foreign_key `user_id` instead of email in all related models, your scaffold generation would be something like this (I've changed the naming slightly from yours, but you get the idea)

```
rails g scaffold TimeSheet user_id:integer day:date hours_worked:integer minutes_worked:integer
```

Then you need to update your `User` model and the newly created `TimeSheet` model to create the associations between the two models

See rails guides for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

```
class User
  # ... 
  has_many :time_sheets
end

class TimeSheet
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You will need to remove the user_id from the scaffold generated views and set it in the controller during `create` and `update` actions

```
def create
  @time_sheet = TimeSheet.new(params[:time_sheet])
  @time_sheet.user = current_user

  # ....
```

Comment: I was able to get that working, so now how do I only show the log of hours that were made by that user? When I log into another account, it still shows the full list

Comment: scope the list that is returned - `current_user.time_sheets` - i highly recommend reading the rails guides  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ - lots of good info there